# $\frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{1^2+2^2}+\frac{1}{1^2+2^2+3^2}+...\to ?\;\;$ (Click here.)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, fractions

$$\frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{1^2+2^2}+\frac{1}{1^2+2^2+3^2}+\dots\to~?$$
I tried like below 
$$\frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{1^2+2^2}+\frac{1}{1^2+2^2+3^2}+\dots=\\\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1^2+2^2+3^2+\dots+n^2}=\\\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}}=\\\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{6}{n(n+1)(2n+1)}=\\
$$
Then I can use the fraction ,but $$\frac{1}{n(n+1)(2n+1)}=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{-4}{2n+1}$$ This is ugly to turn into telescopic series .
Can you help me to find :series converge to ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(n%3D1,infinity,6%2F(n(n%2B1)(2n%2B1))

Comment: $$\frac{2}{2n} + \frac{2}{2n+2} - \frac{4}{2n+1} = 2\biggl(\frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{2n+1}\biggr) - 2\biggl(\frac{1}{2n+1} - \frac{1}{2n+2}\biggr)$$

Comment: One cannot solve this problem using telescope series because the answer involves $\log$, right?

Comment: @DanielFischer Darn, you stole the cake.

Comment: Perhaps the title should be changed to "Sum of 1 over the sum of the first n squares"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Trying to avoid Daniel Fischer's approach.

$$\frac2{(2n)(2n+1)(2n+2)}=\frac1{(2n)(2n+1)}-\frac1{(2n+1)(2n+2)}$$

Collect the terms by their signs:

$$S=12\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n(n+1)}$$

Now apply partial fractions on this nicely and it becomes

$$S=12\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}n+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

You can then collect the terms again to get

$$S=6+12\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}n$$

Upon which you may use the Maclaurin expansion of $\ln(x+1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from 
$$S=6 \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{4}{2 n+1}+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
I changed the index $n\to n+1$
$$S=6 \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \left(\frac{1}{n+2}-\frac{2}{n+\frac{3}{2}}+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$$
Then I applied an amazing property of 
digamma function that can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Regularization)
 and I got

$$S=6 \left(-\psi (1)-\psi (2)+2 \psi \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)$$
which gives ($\gamma $ is Euler-Mascheroni constant)
$$S=6 \left(2 \gamma -1+2 \psi \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)=6 (3-2 \log 4)$$

Answer (score 0):

When I post it , I find an idea ...
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{6}{n(n+1)(2n+1)}=\\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{6\times 2 \times 2}{(2n)(2n+2)(2n+1)}=\\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{24}{(2n)(2n+2)(2n+1)}=\\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{24}{1}(\frac{1}{(2n)(2n+1)(2n+2)})=\\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{24}{2}(\frac{1}{(2n)(2n+1)}-\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)})=\\
12\times \frac{1}{2\times 3}=2$$ but wolfram says $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{6}{n(n+1)(2n+1)}=6(3 - 4log(2))$$ Is there something I had missed  ?

Comment: The step where you turned the sum to $12 \times \dfrac1{2\times3}$ is invalid.

Comment: Oh...I got my mistake .$$f(n)=\frac{1}{2n(2n+1)} \to f(n+1) \neq \frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}$$

Comment: This should probably be an edit to your original post rather than an answer, seeing as it is a) wrong and b) asks another question (Is there something I had missed?)